# Stuck at GRUB command line after editing grub.cfg and other changes

Tags: boot, grub2

I was playing around with GRUB, then I tried to reboot and I can't enter my operating systems (Windows and Ubuntu).

It looks like I've rewritten something very important because it only shows me the GRUB command line. I've tried to `set root` and then load `vmlinuz`, but it tells me that I need to specify some root option correctly.

I was doing a lot of things with grub and I don't remember everything exactly. I just remember that I tried something like `grub-mkconfig recheck`. I was also editing `grub.cfg`. I have read `grub.cfg` with `cat` and it looks normal.

Comment: I've proceed a bit. I'm now in kernek but I can still use only bash.

Comment: Related: [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried to boot with a LiveCD, and fix with Boot-Repair?

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair

boot-repair
```

It is straightforward to use, and worked for me before.
[image: basic UI]

and it allows yo to change kernel options as well:
[image: advance UI]